# Why transpose position and help with equation expansion

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, coordinate-systems, transpose

[image: Snap of the paper]

I was reading this paper and I found this - $x$ is transpose of $(x,y,z)$

and $\theta$ is transpose of $(\phi,\theta,\psi)$.

*Why they are transpose ?*

**And what are their expansion ?**

Comment: The main reason for writing transposed version is that column vectors takes up too much space in typesetting.  Compare $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}^T$ or $(x,y,z)^T$.

Comment: $R<sub>x</sub>$ =  \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&cos(\alpha)&sin(\alpha)\\0&-sin(\alpha)&cos(\alpha)\end{bmatrix}
Vector rotation around Y-axis can be represented as: 

$R<sub>y</sub>$ =  \begin{bmatrix}cos(\beta)&0&-sin(\beta)\\0&1&0\\sin(\beta)&0&cos(\beta)\end{bmatrix}

Vector rotation around Z-axis can be represented as:

$R<sub>z</sub>$ = \begin{bmatrix}cos(\gamma)&sin(\gamma)&0\\-sin(\gamma)&cos(\gamma)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Now final rotation matrix can be calculated and represented as:

$R = R<sub>x</sub> * R<sub>y</sub> * R<sub>z</sub>$


Is this equivalent to $\theta$ ?

Comment: Just wondering about community guidelines, should you perhaps cite the paper?

Comment: Is there anything wrong ?

Should I really have to cite paper to question ? @BookBookBook

Comment: Got no idea... I was told to cite whenever I use, screenshot, etc anyone's work